# html(bootstrap) column and div allignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So i am working on a html/css website using bootstrap for responsive websites. Now i came to a point i don't know how exactly to do it.

i have this html:

```css
#email_sub{
 margin:0 auto;
 background: #15b4dc;
 color:fff;
 border: 0px solid white;
 padding-top:10px;
 padding-bottom:10px;
 font-size: 100%;
}

#email_pt1{
 float:left;
 color:#fff;
    display: inline-block;
 border: 1px solid white;
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 padding-top:4px;
 padding-bottom:5px;
 padding-left:2%;
 padding-right:2%;
}
#email_pt1 .form-inline input.form-control{width:70%;}

.emailbtn{position:absolute; right:0px; bottom:0;}


#email_pt2{
 float:right;
 border: 1px solid white;
 padding-top:0px;
 margin:0, auto;
 width:100%;
}
```

```html
<!--email sub bar-->
<div id="email_sub">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div id="email_pt1">
     <form class="form-inline" role="form">
      <!--form gorup-->
       <label for="email">Order news </label>
       <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Vnesite vaš email...">
      <!--end-->
      <button type="submit" class="emailbtn btn-default">SUBMIT</button>
     </form>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div id="email_pt2">
     <!--col2-->

    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div id="email_pt3">
     <!--col2-->
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

And i want to make the 2nd and 3rd column to look like this:
[image]

so a square picture on left side and two lines of text next to it. How can i make it look like that?

Comment: where exactly do you want to place those squares ?

Comment: One row should have two columns, left one will have your image, right one should have two rows full column width. I think this is what you're looking for http://codepen.io/cyberhck/pen/yerBdd

Comment: yes, i was looking for something like that, i just wasnt sure if i should make new rows and columns inside that column or if i should use DIV's, but this looks nice, i will try it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want https://jsfiddle.net/kh0prtc4/4/ ?

change `<div class="col-sm-3">` to `<div class="col-sm-6">`

Comment: But bootstrap allows only 12 columns, if  ichange 3 to 6, i will have 6+6+6 =18, its not the problem of column size, i want to use `<div class="col-sm-3">` but inside of it i want to create something like on the picture i attached

Comment: @mheonyae Did it look right? setting 6, 6 and 6 does not = 18, because bootstrap works off of a 12 column grid system, setting 6, 6, 6 creates one row of 6 and 6, and a second row with one 6.

Comment: the other option you have is to wrap the two divs in its own `col-sm-6` then set each one inside to `col-sm-12` both ways should work just fine. see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kh0prtc4/5/

Answer (score 0):

Just add inside another row:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <img class="img-responsive"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        Text text<br/>
        text text
    </div>
</div>
```